# JW Player Remove Fullscreen boxing

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I've got a video (more than one actually, but that doesent matter), here is the JW setup:

```
  jwplayer('myvideo').setup({
    'allowscriptaccess': 'always',
    'flashplayer': 'video/player.swf',
    'file': 'video/clips/video.mp4',
    'controlbar': 'over',
    'width': 620,
    'height': 480,
  });
```

In normal mode, it displays fine, however in Fullscreen:

[image: This sucks]

The black border is not supposed to be there.

I checked the example in the JW Setup Wizard, and their fullscreen works fine. Why doesent mine? Can it be my video? What should I do? Thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT**: By using stretching = fill, I got it to fill the black borders, however, it makes it too big. I need it to fit the screen size :)

Comment: Jeff, I don't know what you're talking.  JWPlayer should work fine.  Do you have a working example?

Comment: @vol - http://xskysoftware.com/clickbank/thank-you.php - Try fullscreening the video, you will see the black boxes. I am trying to remove them, without zooming the video. Once you have seen the boxes, let me know, and I will change it to the zooming-bug

Comment: Do you mean the black fill on the left/right of the video?  Isn't that due to your video ratio? Also, your stuff doesn't work in Google:Chrome

Comment: @vol - yes, the black fill. It shouldnt be, because when I play it on my desktop, it shows fine. What is the Chrome issue?

Comment: @Jeff, What are the dimensions (width and height or x and y) of your videos?

Comment: @Jeff: chrome issue is it simply doesn't play and images aren't available.  I'd suggest just viewing the page in Chrome.
@Rob: it looks like he's using 640x480, which is fine in small screen view, but on my widescreen monitor, that's definitely going to cause boxing/bordering, since it's not 16:9.

Comment: @vol - Alright, will get Chrome. The images are stored on a CDN+CloudFront, maybe thats it? So what can I do in order for the fullscreen to work properly?

Comment: @vol - I tried changing the width and height to different aspect ratios, did not help either

Comment: @vol - Chrome works fine on my end.

Comment: @Jeff: It's working fine now for me too.. must have been a connection issue (none of the images or videos were loading).  In order for it to work, you'll have to change the base file aspect ratio, which most likely means you'll have to record the video in a different size, or reformat in a different size.  Reformatting it will most likely mean either something is going to be cropped (going from larger resolution to smaller), or something will be added (going to smaller to larger, will add borders, like what you already have).

Comment: I am rendering my video file in the exact same size my JW Player is, however I am afraid that wont give me a good fullscreen result. Will report back boss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Voltron (represent).
If you speak of the black on the left and right, that's due to your video resolution ratio. 4:3 and 16:9 are the tow common ratios for monitors. Fullscreen, the ratio will just be whatever your monitor is. So if your video resolution is 1024x720p, someone with a 1024x720- monitor won't see and black. Simple.

ETA (due to comments):

No matter how big the resolution is. It's the ratio that determines where the black is. It's just filler. If the black wasn't there, the video would have to stretch and distort. It's not the amount of pixels that matters. It's the width x height ratio that matters.

Comment: Well, my video file's resolution is 1440x1080, isnt that big enough? I got a 24'' monitor btw

Comment: @Jeff: my minimum default monitor resolution at home 1680x1050, at work I think it's a little smaller/square.  I forget how Hulu does it, but many sites do a screen sniffer to dynamically display different aspect ratios.

Comment: @vol - Even when I make the size of my JW extremely big, the fullscreen-size is still the same :(

Comment: @Jeff: you should check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_resolution.  They also have a chart that Steam provided, which shows a surveyed result of people's setup (notice 16:9 was most popular amongst Steam users).  Note: Steam is mostly for games, so there are demographics involved.

Comment: Accepted this - changed the resolution of the video, which fixed it. Quality kinda sucks though, but meh.